# How to use JS detect user close page on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, frontend

I want to detect user close my page using js, in Chrome/Firefox I use onbeforeunload event, but in Safari (on macOS and iOS) it doesn't work (but MDN say It work...)

In Safari on macOS, onbeforeunload only work first time refresh/close page.

I try unload, beforeunload, pagehide also not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
window.unload = function () 
{ 
// add code here 
};
```

Here is some documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

Comment: Thank for your answer but It doesn't work on iOS's Safari